# Native MongoDB: Why is my switch statement not working with field names but only hard coded values?

Tags: mongodb, operators

Problem: I was trying to find a way to only update my lastModified field, if user inputted field values actually change on update. Originally, I included the lastModified field in the (non-aggregate) $set object, which always updated it as new Date() changes even if the other update fields don't. This led to misleading timestamp records.

Eventually I was able to get a solution using aggregation in update but, something doesn't quite work as I expected it to. I can only assume it's a bug unless my understanding is wrong. Please see the code snippets.

Correction: Neither of the below works (**However**, they do work if I hard replace the field path with values e.g. changing '$firstName' to 'Steve' works)

```
{
    $set: {
        lastModified: {
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    {
                        case: {
                            $ne: ['$firstName', firstName],
                        },
                        then: new Date(),
                    },
                    {
                        case: {
                            $ne: ['$lastName', lastName],
                        },
                        then: new Date(),
                    },
                ],
                default: '$lastModified',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

```
{
    $set: {
        lastModified: {
            $switch: {
                branches: [
                    {
                        case: {
                            $not: { $eq: ['$firstName', firstName] }
                        },
                        then: new Date(),
                    },
                    {
                        case: {
                            $not: { $eq: ['$lastName', lastName] }
                        },
                        then: new Date(),
                    },
                ],
                default: '$lastModified',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

If anyone can provide some clarity with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Edit: Further details added**

```
// firstName = 'Steve', lastName = 'Jobs'
// In db, $firstName field = 'John', $lastName field = 'Doe'
// the intention is to compare user input with db fields and 
// detect changes using the switch statement
const { firstName, lastName } = req.body

db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                firstName,
                lastName,
            },
        },
        {
            $set: {
                lastModified: {
                    $switch: {
                        branches: [
                            {
                                case: {
                                    $not: {
                                        $eq: ['$firstName', firstName],
                                    },
                                },
                                then: new Date(),
                            },
                            {
                                case: {
                                    $not: {
                                        $eq: ['$lastName', lastName],
                                    },
                                },
                                then: new Date(),
                            },
                        ],
                        default: '$lastModified',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    { ignoreUndefined: true },
)
```

I expect the db document to change from

```
{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    lastModified: ~previous timestamp~
}
```

to

```
{
    firstName: 'Steve',
    lastName: 'Jobs',
    lastModified: ~new timestamp~
}
```

however I get

```
{
    firstName: 'Steve',
    lastName: 'Jobs',
    lastModified: ~previous timestamp~
}
```

It only works if one of the two variables are hardcoded i.e.

```
case: {
    $not: {
        $eq: ['$firstName', firstName],
    },
    then: 'DOES NOT enter here'
},
case: {
    $not: {
        $eq: ['John', firstName],
    },
    then: 'DOES enter here'
},
case: {
    $not: {
        $eq: ['$firstName', 'Steve'],
    },
    then: 'DOES enter here'
},
```

For now, I've decided (for now) to use two queries to update the lastModified field, but I don't really like this approach at all. The second query is:

```
if (modifiedCount > 0 || upsertedCount > 0) {
    dbCollection
            .updateOne(filter, update)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}
```

Comment: Could you include a sample document and an example of the output you're trying to achieve? I tried your code [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y4qn4G2Nq3k) and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VW1Wv04qr5G) and they're behaving how I'd expect them to.

Comment: I've added some more details. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your update statement isn't working is because you have two `$set` stages back-to-back. Let's walk through what happens when you update this document:

```
{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    lastModified: ~previous timestamp~
}
```

The first `$set` stage will update the `firstName` and `lastName` fields, resulting in a document like this:

```
{
    firstName: 'Steve',
    lastName: 'Jobs',
    lastModified: ~previous timestamp~
}
```

This resulting document is then passed to the second `$set` stage. Inside of the `$switch`, you are comparing the values of `$firstName` and `firstName` and `$lastName` and `lastName`. But because you have already updated these values in the previous stage, they will always be the same.

You can combine the two stages into one, this way the `$firstName` and `$lastName` variables in the `$switch` cases refer to their original values:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id },
    [
        {
            $set: {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                lastModified: {
                    $switch: {
                        branches: [
                            {
                                case: { $ne: [ "$firstName", firstName ] },
                                then: new Date()
                            },
                            {
                                case: { $ne: [ "$lastName", lastName ] },
                                then: new Date(),
                            }
                        ],
                        default: "$lastModified"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    { ignoreUndefined: true },
)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense. It works as expected now, thanks a million!!!